# bootstrap-datepicker: How to use specific time zone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I created a small program to select the date using [bootstrap-datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) and write it to MySQL.

The catch is that this date must be local to `Europe/Berlin` regardless where the user is at the moment.

```
$(....).datepicker({ startDate: 'today' });
```

My question is: how do I set `startDate` to be local to specific timezone <del>without using server side code (PHP) or any other libraries</del>?

I tried using `moment` + `moment-timezone` but it's also showing the local browser date.

```
var todaysDate = moment().tz('Europe/Berlin').format();
$(...).datepicker({ startDate: todaysDate });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just needed

`moment.tz.setDefault("Europe/Berlin");`

After which moment generated the correct date without using `tz()`. Also make sure that format matches.

```
var todaysDate = moment().format('D MMM YYYY');
$(...).datepicker({ format: 'dd M yyyy', startDate: todaysDate });
```

Comment: I am getting the below error. _Uncaught TypeError: option startDate is not recognized!_

Answer (score 4):

The date object will always be in Local time zone (browser based).

`dateObj.getTime()` will give you absolute milliseconds.

http://momentjs.com/ is great library for timezone conversions.

**EDIT**

About how:

```
 var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");
 var losAngeles = newYork.clone().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
 var london     = newYork.clone().tz("Europe/London");
 
 newYork.format();    // 2014-06-01T12:00:00-04:00
 losAngeles.format(); // 2014-06-01T09:00:00-07:00
 london.format();     // 2014-06-01T17:00:00+01:00
```

and

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

This is the exact code from their website. If you don't pass `America/New_York` and just simply `moment("2014-06-01 12:00")` it will get local time.

`moment().utcOffset()` function will get you utcOffset if you want to know which timezone moment interprets.

See the demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uneu1wwf/)

**EDIT 2022**
momenjs is deprecated, use date-fns or luxon

Comment: I tried using moment + moment-timezone but it's also showing the local browser date.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/vrdrxp0z/1/) can get you in the right direction?

HTML

```
<div class='input-group date date-time-picker'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="Start Time"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var options = {
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii',
    autoclose: true
};

$('.date-time-picker').datetimepicker(options).on("changeDate", function (e) {
    var TimeZoned = new Date(e.date.setTime(e.date.getTime() + 
                            (e.date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)));
    $(this).datetimepicker('setDate', TimeZoned);
});
```

Comment: hell no idea what does mean: "ii" in time format - and also, why you are multiplicate it by 60k?

Comment: @Lightning3 That's the format used by the plugin: http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ . `getTimezoneOffset()` returns the offset in minutes, `getTime()` returns current time in milliseconds. So it's just a conversion from minutes to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```html
export const convertToCST= (date) => {
   var convertToCT = date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
        timeZone: 'CST',
    })
    var day = convertToCT.split("/")[1];
    var month = convertToCT.split("/")[0] < 10 ? `0${convertToCT.split("/")[0]}` : convertToCT.split("/")[0];
    var year = (convertToCT.split("/")[2]).split(",")[0];
    var formtedDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`
    return formtedDate;
}

<input required type="date" className="form-control" value={convertToCST(new Date(date))} />
```

ex

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).