# JQ UI DatePicker - timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to force [JQ UI DatePicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker) work in given timezone, not local?

For example: `America/Toronto`

Comment: I don't believe this functionality is available on the datepicker by default. You would need to work out the current timezone of the client and then add/subtract the offset to get the time in Toronto

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918017/bootstrap-datepicker-how-to-use-specific-time-zone

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could solve this propose with [momentJS](http://momentjs.com/) + set  defaultDate option JQ UI DatePicker

```
//Set default timezone for all new momentJS instances 
moment.tz.setDefault('America/Toronto');

//Today date and time in America/Toronto timezone correction
var setDate = moment(); 

//Set defaultDate in proper date format for datepicker

 $(element).datepicker(
 {
     defaultDate:setDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY')
 }
```

**Remember**: Don't call toDate() method, use format() for getting proper date and time result in given timezone.